# How do I control property names (casing) of JSON-deserialised objects through service/WebInvoke methods

Tags: .net, wcf, json, rest, serialization

I'm hosting a service using code like this:

```
// Set up the test service
testServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(TestTrelloService), testServiceAddress);
testServiceHost.Open();
```

And I'm sending a PUT with RestSharp, to a method like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "cards/{cardId}?key={key}")]
public void UpdateCard(string key, string cardId, Card updatedCard)
{
    // ...
}
```

`key` and `cardId` are coming from the url/querystring, and updatedCard is the request body (s JSON).

Everything works fine if my Card class looks like this:

```
public class Card
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

The JSON data passed in the body is correctly deserialised into a `Card` object with the `id` propert set.

However, I want my class to have different casing on the property. It actually looks like this:

```
public class Card
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. I've tried adding various attributes to try and control this (including `[DataMember(Name="id")]`), but nothing seems to work.

Is there a way I can control the property names for the JSON deserialisation done for my `WebInvoke`/service method?

Answer (score 2):

Well, now I feel lame... I fixed it!

```
[DataContract]
public class Card
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I was missing the `DataContract` attribute, which appears to be required for it to read the `DataMember` attribute!